# Custom values in gaauge view

Tags: android, gauge

I am developing an application that consists of a gauge view. I downloaded gauge view library from [here](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView). And I want multiple gauge views using same library with different scale inside the gauges. For the first gauge I did it successfully with the help of my friends of stack overflow. Coming to second gauge I want the scale with minimum value of 0 and maximum value of 1, between them sub scale divisions of 0.2 (Multiples of 2 that is 0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8 and finally 1.0). I did it according to the first gauge and for scale I also did the same with different sub scale divisions values it was showing all zeros among the sub scale values please help me with this working for 3 hours. My scale formula is:

```
  /*Declaration*/  



    private float mScalePosition;
        private float mScaleStartValue;
        private float mScaleEndValue;
        private float mScaleStartAngle;
        private float[] mRangeValues;
        public static final float SCALE_START_VALUE = 0f;
            public static final float SCALE_END_VALUE = 1f;
            public static final float SCALE_START_ANGLE = 90;
            public static final float SCALE_DIVISIONS = 5f;
            public static final float SCALE_SUBDIVISIONS = 10f;
               mScaleRotation = (mScaleStartAngle+180)%360 ;
                mDivisionValue = (mScaleEndValue - mScaleStartValue) / mDivisions;
                mSubdivisionValue = mDivisionValue / mSubdivisions;
                mSubdivisionAngle = (360- 2 * mScaleStartAngle) / (mDivisions * mSubdivisions);
```

this is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:gauge="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.demo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <!-- <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        gauge:showNeedle="false"
        gauge:showOuterRim="false"
        gauge:showOuterShadow="true"
        gauge:showRanges="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textUnit="MBs"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />




    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        gauge:showNeedle="false"
        gauge:showOuterRim="false"
        gauge:showOuterShadow="true"
        gauge:showRanges="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textUnit="MBs"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp" /> -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="CHECK" />

    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view1"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

     <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.AmmeterGaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view2"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```